# How would I create a DCG to parse queries about a database?

Tags: database, prolog, dcg

I'm just playing around with learning Prolog and am trying to build a database of information and then use natural English to query about relationships.  How would I go about doing this?

Example:

```
%facts

male(bob).
female(sarah).
male(timmy).
female(mandy).

parent(bob, timmy).
parent(bob, mandy).
parent(sarah, timmy).
parent(sarah, mandy).

spouse(bob, sarah).
spouse(sarah, bob).

%some basic rules

married(X,Y) :- spouse(X,Y).
married(X,Y) :- spouse(Y,X).

child(C,X) :- parent(X,C).
```

Now, I want to ask some "who" questions, i.e., "who is the parent of timmy".

I read something about DCGs, but, can anyone point me to some good resources or get me going in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: Click on the `dcg` tag above this comment. Then on the right near the top is the `dcg` tag again. To the right of it is a link for `info`; click on that. The info page has lots of good links.

Comment: Thanks! aaaaaaaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would also like to ask a "who" question: In a fact like

```
parent(X, Y).
```

**WHO** is actually the parent? Is it `X` or is it `Y`?

To make this clearer, I strongly recommend you use a naming convention that makes clear what each argument means. For example:

```
parent_child(X, Y).
```

Now, to translate "informal" questions to Prolog goals that reason over your data, consider for example the following **DCG**:

```
question(Query, Person) --> [who,is], question_(Query, Person).

question_(parent_child(Parent,Child), Parent) --> [the,parent,of,Child].
question_(parent_child(Parent,Child), Child)  --> [the,child,of,Parent].
question_(married(Person0,Person), Person)    --> [married,to,Person0].
question_(spouse(Person0,Person), Person)     --> [the,spouse,of,Person0].
```

Here, I am assuming you have already converted given sentences to **tokens**, which I represent as Prolog **atoms**.

In order to conveniently work with DCGs, I strongly recommend the following declaration:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
```

This lets you write for example:

```
?- Xs = "abc".
Xs = [a, b, c].
```

Thus, it becomes very convenient to work with such programs. I leave converting such lists of *characters* to *tokens* as an exercise for you.

Once you have such tokens, you can use the DCG to relate *lists* of such tokens to Prolog *queries* over your program.

For example:

```
?- phrase(question(Query, Person), [who,is,the,parent,of,timmy]).
Query = parent_child(Person, timmy) .
```

Another example:

```
?- phrase(question(Query, Person), [who,is,the,spouse,of,sarah]).
Query = spouse(sarah, Person).
```

To actually **run** such queries, simply post them as goals. For example:

```
?- phrase(question(Query, Person), [who,is,married,to,bob]),
   Query.
Query = married(bob, sarah),
Person = sarah .
```

This shows that such a conversion is quite straight-forward in Prolog.

As @GuyCoder already mentioned in the comments, make sure to check out [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) for more information about DCG notation!

Comment: Thanks!  That helps a lot!!

Comment: Quick question!  If I've gotten user input and atomized into a LIST, then pass the list into: phrase(question(Query, Person), LIST) in the program, and then call Query, why am I only seeing "true" and not the actual result like when putting in phrase(question(Query, Person), [who,is,the,parent,of,timmy]) from the command line?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to relate `Person` to the query you are constructing? Look whether you get a **singleton warning** when you compile your program. This means that a variable name is used only once in a clause, which is always suspicious and usually means that you have either forgotten to relate it to other variables, or have mistyped its name. In the examples I posted, the `Person` in `question(Query, Person)` is used to let the toplevel report actual solutions for this very variable. The DCG clauses refer to this variable to relate it to the person we are looking for.